# Solving Non-linear ode with elliptic integrals

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, nonlinear-system

I am trying to obtain a solution for $y(x)$ satisfying the following ODE

\begin{equation}
y'(x)=\sqrt{Ay(x)^4+By(x)^3+Cy(x)^2+Dy(x)}
\end{equation}
where ${A,B,C,D}$ are constants. From what I can tell, the solution will be given in terms of elliptic integrals (FriCAS gives an obscure output in terms of the WeirstraussPInverse function) but I am unfamiliar with methods involving those.

Is there any way to approach this kind of differential equation? Thanks!

Comment: It is a separable differential equation with the solution being an elliptic function, the inverse of the elliptic integral shown

Answer (score 1):

As @Tyma Gaidash commented, write the equation as
$$x'=\frac 1{\sqrt{Ay^4+By^3+Cy^2+Dy}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{A}}\frac 1{\sqrt{y(y-a)(y-b)(y-c)}}$$ and
$$\int\frac {dy}{\sqrt{y(y-a)(y-b)(y-c)}}=-\frac 2{\sqrt{c(a-b)}}F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a-b)(y-c) }{(c-b)(y-a) }}\right)|\frac{a
   (c-b)}{c (a-b)}\right)$$

Comment: Hi Claude. Thank you for the answer. Can you clear up the following confusion about your integral formula? When I put your integral into Mathematica 12 the result given is:
\begin{equation}
-\dfrac{2 \text{EllipticF}\left[\text{Arcsin}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{y(b-a)}}{b(y-a)}\right)\Big|\dfrac{a(c-b)}{c(a-b)}\right]}{\sqrt{c(b-a)}}
\end{equation}
which when plotted is explicitly different from the result you show. Any idea what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: Note there should be a root in the denominator of the Arcsin argument. I did not see the error in time to edit the comment

Comment: @pill. I had a typo : the front minus was missing but that is all. Differentiate your and my expressions. Cheers :-)